# Flush IIS7 logs manually on remote machine

Tags: iis, iis-7, logging

I know how to flush IIS7 logs when I'm logged on some machine:

```
netsh http flush logbuffer
```

How can I do it on another machine?

Comment: I think simplest way is to use psexec

Comment: @Kostia Shiian: If this is the only way (as seen from answers here) you may place it as answer. Also think it's possible via PowerShell, but have no time to test it for now.